# How to convert from Inverse Fast Fourier Transform to .wav?

Tags: c#, wav, waveform, fft, inverse

I used made a fft to make a band pass filter.
After that I made the ifft to inverse it and pass it to time domain.

My ifft has the same length of the fft.

The ifft must be longer or is there a way to make it longer?
How do I pass this ifft to .wav?

Comment: The IFFT output should be the same length as the original input.  You might need to take the amplitude of the IFFT output because it will contain imaginary numbers.  I don't know how C# formats this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WAV file format is documented pretty well (see below). It's basically some header information followed by the raw sample data.

first result with Google:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: In the data I just need to put the result from IFFT?
Or do I need to make something to IFFT first?

Comment: Yeah, I would think so. If it's a normal sampled audio signal it's quite easy to check.